# Selected SMS by keyword to Listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

How to select sms by keyword from body to listview?

Current progress: sms are shown in listview, but all sms are displayed. I just want to display only selected sms by keyword. This is my code.

```
public List<String> getSMS() {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        cursor = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, null, null,
                null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        for (boolean hasData = cursor.moveToFirst(); hasData; hasData = cursor
                .moveToNext()) {
            String body = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("body"));
            list.add(body);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: are you getting any error???

Comment: nothing, sms just display all to listview

Comment: @Ashadi is this working or not still?

Answer (score 1):

If you add body content to listview, then why not compare with keyword before adding?

```
String keyword = "hello"
try {
    for (boolean hasData = cursor.moveToFirst(); hasData; hasData = cursor
            .moveToNext()) {
        String body = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("body"));
        if(body.toLowerCase().contains(keywoed.toLowerCase()))
            list.add(body);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I have used `toLowerCase()` for case insensitive compare.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks @Mystic it's work... sorry I'm newbie here cannot vote up