# how to specific sms display on my listview

Tags: java, android, sms

I want specific sms to be displayed in my listview in application. Now using below code all sms are displayed in listview.

```
MainActivity.java 
{
    ListView lViewSMS = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewSMS); 
    if(fetchInbox()!=null)
    { 
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, fetchInbox());
        lViewSMS.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
} 
public ArrayList fetchInbox()
{
    ArrayList sms = new ArrayList(); 
    Uri uriSms = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");        
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uriSms, new String[]{"_id", "address", "date", "body"},null,null,null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();        
    while  (cursor.moveToNext())
    {
        String address = cursor.getString(1);
        String body = cursor.getString(3); 
        System.out.println("======&gt; Mobile number =&gt; "+address);
        System.out.println("=====&gt; SMS Text =&gt; "+body); 
        sms.add("Address="+address+"\n"+"SMS="+body);
    }
return sms;
}
```

Comment: which specific SMS you wanna show in List ? then Just add desired SMS in the ArrayList

Comment: Do you want [sms according to search keyword](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25987068/1777090)? Be clear.

Answer (score -1):

You Can filter the Sms from cursor. See the [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14721772/get-sms-of-specific-phone-number) they filter the Sms by phone number. similarly you can filter by sms body etc.

Comment: but that sms not display on inbox message of phone